# quickly cast a vector of unsigned char into a vector of POD struct and vice versa

Tags: c++, file, vector

I want to read/write binary data, essentially a vector of plain old data struct.

I managed to do so with arrays of char, but now I need to convert those arrays back and forth to an vector of struct.

I already managed to do this by reading/writing directly into files:

```
int main() {
    struct thing { float f; char c; };
    std::vector<thing> write_this = { {2,'c'},{5,'f'},{543,'e'} };

    std::ofstream outfile{ "test.bin", std::ios::binary };
    outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(write_this.data()),
        write_this.size() * sizeof(decltype(write_this)::value_type));
    outfile.close();

    std::vector<thing> result(3);

    std::ifstream infile{ "test.bin", std::ios::binary };
    infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(result.data()),
        result.size() * sizeof(thing));

    for (auto& i : result)
        std::cout << i.f << " " << i.c << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Since I want to store several different segments of data into a file, I'm using vectors of unsigned char as an intermediary. I now need to cast an array of char or vector of char to a vector of struct, and vice versa.

What's the simplest/cleanest/fastest way to do so?

Comment: Short answer: Don't.  Write and read the segments directly.  Otherwise you'll have to `memcpy` from the vector of char to the vector of structs.

Comment: Your posted code looks good to me. Are you running into any problems with it?

Comment: no, I just want to cast a vector<unsigned char> to a vector<thing>, thing being a POD stuct

Comment: Code like that is not portable. For example, not all compilers use same alignment for your `struct`. If you really want to write such code, at very least add some checks like `static_assert(sizeof thing == 8, "This code only works id data is aligned to 4 bytes");`

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica how can I write several segments of different types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreword: Note that the written data is not portable to other systems, and for some PODs (ones that contain bit fields) not even to other processes on same system compiled by a different compiler - unless those systems are somehow guaranteed to have identical binary representation.

Also, memory references in the written data will be meaningless to other processes, even to separate executions of the same program.

> quickly cast a vector of unsigned char into a vector of POD struct and vice versa

You could do this:

```
static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<thing>);
constexpr int s = sizeof(thing);
int n = 3;
std::vector<unsigned char> result_raw(n * s);
unsigned char* data = result_raw.data();
infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), n * s);

// ->
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    unsigned char temp[s];
    unsigned char* addr = data + i * s;
    std::memcpy(temp, addr, s);
    new (addr) thing;
    std::memcpy(addr, temp, s);
}
thing* result = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<thing*>(data));
// <-
```

Now, you have a pointer to the first `thing` in the vector. Beautiful part about this is that the part between the arrow comments that creates the objects and makes the program well-defined compiles to zero instructions (as long as you enable optimisation).

You don't get a `std::vector<thing>` though. To get that, you must copy all of the from one vector another. Or you could read directly onto the vector of things like in your example. But you didn't want to do the latter, and former is slower than not copying.

---

In future, if [p0593rX](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0593r2.html) proposal is adopted, this block of code that does nothing could be greatly simplified.